# Lazy operations with haskell/cryptonite

Tags: haskell

I'm using cryptonite to perform AES256 encryption in CTR mode. So far, everything works fine with ByteStrings, but for better space efficiency (some files may be big) I'd like to switch to lazy IO and lazy ByteStrings.

The type signature for ctrCombine in the cryptonite package is:

`ctrCombine :: ByteArray ba => cipher -> IV cipher -> ba -> ba`

The problem is: ByteString.Lazy is not an instance of ByteArray. If I try to pass a lazy ByteString to ctrCombine, GHC complains with the following error:

`No instance for (memory-0.14.6:Data.ByteArray.Types.ByteArray LBS.ByteString) arising from a use of ‘ctrCombine’`

Is it possible to perform lazy encryption with cryptonite? Or is there some package out there that implements ByteArray for lazy ByteStrings? Or am I missing something obvious? I could easily write my own version of ctrCombine based on ecbEncrypt that operates on lazy ByteStrings, especially as AES is well suited for streaming, but I'd like not to reinvent the wheel. (And also, that would violate the "don't write your own crypto" principle.)

Comment: Does the [StreamCipher](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.24/docs/Crypto-Cipher-Types.html#t:StreamCipher) class help you?

Comment: Also, is https://github.com/haskell-crypto/cryptonite/issues/86 insightful?

Answer (score 1):

**Specific Answers to Specific Questions**

> Is it possible to perform lazy encryption with cryptonite? [...] I could easily write my own version of ctrCombine based on ecbEncrypt that operates on lazy ByteStrings, especially as AES is well suited for streaming, but I'd like not to reinvent the wheel.

All the primitives are there but as you noted they aren't really made to be composed as easily as you would like.

> Or is there some package out there that implements ByteArray for lazy ByteStrings?

I hope not.  Any type that is an instance of `ByteArray` must also be an instance of `ByteArrayAccess` and thus have a function that gets the entire byte array in contiguous memory via `withByteArray :: ba -> (Ptr p -> IO a) -> IO a`.  This is counter to the point of lazy bytestrings. It is more honest to have people use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.toStrict` first.

> Or am I missing something obvious?

Well there is `toStrict` as mentioned above.

> (And also, that would violate the "don't write your own crypto" principle.)

If you are using counter mode directly then you are already at a level many people would consider "writing your own crypto" even if it isn't what the adage was traditionally about.

**An Alternative**

The cryptonite API seeks to make the common thing easy more than be a foundational underpinning that I'd once hoped for the Haskell community. An alaternative is the crypto-api, which is more flexible at the cost of not being as simple for the end user.

Specific to your question: in crypto-api there is a `Crypto.Classes.ctrLazy` function.  Second, even if there was only the strict ByteString version you could take advantage of the returned `IV` to build a lazy counter mode without resorting to ECB.

It is the lack of return IVs, and in some cases the use of exceptions instead of sum types, that I feel was the original point of distinction between the "keep simple things simple" APIs Vincent publishes and the maximally flexible low level APIs I promoted in crypto-api and other packages from that era.